# Double conditions redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to permanently redirect my pages to https + www.

I'm using the code below but it doesn't work when I enter https://example.com. It does nothing and displays the page without adding the www.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Do you have other rules in your .htaccess before this rule?

Comment: @anubhava Thank you for your answer. No, I don't.

Comment: Your rule looks like it should work. Is mod rewrite enabled on your server?

Comment: @starkeen Yes because when the URL doesn't contain https or www, it redirects to https with www...

Comment: What error do you get when you go to https:// ?

Comment: @starkeen I have no error at all. http+www redirects to https+www ; no-http and no-www redirects to https+www but https+no-www displays the page and doesn't redirect to https+www.

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: @starkeen Yes, I did it several times and also tested it on another browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133994/discussion-between-cyclone200-and-starkeen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the given redirect rule. It seems problem is that OP is executing shown rule from `<VirtualHost *:80>` section. Those rules will obviously won't fire if request is `https://`. OP can do one of the two thing to fix the problem:

1. Keep same redirect rule in `<VirtualHost *:443>` section as well - `OR`
2. Keep rule in a common place like `.htaccess`

Comment: Indeed, I had not thought that it would influence the rule. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work. It does not add the www when the url already have the https.